# Extract entries from a file ranging from one date to another

Tags: files, find, date

There is a file which has entries with the first and second field as date and time in the following manner : `2015/10/14 00:33:37`.

The file has 100,000+ lines and is constantly updated. Entries in the file need to selected from the earliest Monday 00:00:00 to Sunday 23:59:59.

`2015/10/11 23:55:37    abc1    def1
2015/10/11  23:55:39    abc2    def2
2015/10/11  23:56:19    abc3    def3
2015/10/11  23:56:46    abc4    def4
2015/10/11  23:57:46    abc5    def5
2015/10/12  0:04:25 abc6    def6
2015/10/12  0:04:44 abc7    def7
2015/10/12  0:04:44 abc8    def8
2015/10/12  0:04:44 abc9    def9
2015/10/12  0:04:44 abc10   def10
2015/10/12  0:04:44 abc11   def11
2015/10/12  0:04:44 abc12   def12
2015/10/12  0:04:44 abc13   def13
2015/10/12  0:04:44 abc14   def14
2015/10/12  0:04:44 abc15   def15
2015/10/12  0:04:48 abc16   def16
2015/10/12  0:04:48 abc17   def17
2015/10/12  0:04:48 abc18   def18
2015/10/12  0:04:48 abc19   def19
2015/10/12  0:04:49 abc20   def20
2015/10/12  0:04:49 abc21   def21
2015/10/12  0:08:36 abc22   def22
2015/10/12  0:08:36 abc23   def23
2015/10/12  0:08:36 abc24   def24
2015/10/12  0:08:36 abc25   def25
2015/10/12  0:08:36 abc26   def26
2015/10/12  0:08:36 abc27   def27
2015/10/12  0:08:36 abc28   def28
2015/10/12  0:08:37 abc29   def29
2015/10/12  0:08:37 abc30   def30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shell script fragment builds an extended regular expression (with `/` characters suitably escaped) that contains all of the days from last Monday to the following Sunday, in `YYYY/MM/DD` format.  It then uses that with `grep` to search the logfile.

```sh
DAYS=$(for D in {0..6} ; do 
           date -d "last monday + $D days" +'%Y\\/%m\\/%d'
       done | xargs | 
       sed -e 's/ /|/g'
      )

REGEX="^($DAYS) "

grep -E "$REGEX" logfile.txt
```

If you prefer to use basic regular expressions, change the last few lines to:

```sh
REGEX="^\($DAYS\) "
REGEX=$(printf "%s" "$REGEX" | sed -e 's/\([|]\)/\\\1/g')

grep "$REGEX" logfile.txt
```

Another option is to use `grep`'s `-F` (fixed-string) and `-f` (file) options with the shell's process substitution ability `<( ... )`, like this:

```sh
DAYS=$(for D in {0..6} ; do 
           date -d "last monday + $D days" +'%Y/%m/%d'
       done )

grep -F -f <(echo "$DAYS") logfile.txt
```

or even

```sh
grep -F -f <( for D in {0..6} ; do 
              date -d "last monday + $D days" +'%Y/%m/%d'
              done ) logfile.txt
```

NOTE: these last two versions will match on a date in that format anywhere in the line, not just at the beginning of the line.  with the sample you've given, this is not likely to be a problem.

Comment: @jordanm, you discovered (as i did) that the `sed` is needed there because of the `xargs` :)

Comment: Forgive me if my question is silly. Is there anything wrong with addressing the issue like this instead?

`DAYS1=$(for D in {0..6} ; do
date -d "last monday + $D day" +%Y/%m/%d
done
)

grep  "$DAYS1" logfile.txt`

Comment: if you did that, DAYS1 would have multiple regexps per line.  most of the script is in converting it from that format to regular expression format.  Another option would be to have `DAYS=$(for ... ;date ... ; done)` and then use `grep -F -f <(echo "$DAYS") logfile.txt`.  I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: sorry, i mean to say "DAYS1 would have multiple lines, with **one regexp per line**"